# E[Z] by integrating $\int_{-1}^1 \frac{x^{4/3}+x^{1/3}}{2} dx$

Tags: probability, definite-integrals

I'm a little stuck on this expected value question which involves some integration. The question asks to find the expected value for Z that is $E[Z]$, using some appropriate function $\psi(x)$ where $Z=X^{1/3}$ and the probability density function $f_X(x)=\frac{x+1}{2}$ for $-1\lt x\lt1$

The correct approach would be

$$E[Z]=E[X^{1/3}]=\int_{-1}^1 x^{1/3}\cdot f_X(x)\,dx$$

Since its a monotonically increasing function, the integral doesn't need to be split up into separate integrals.

My difficulty arises when substituting in the terminals for the definite integral, which is different to the actual answer, which again is different to what Wolfram Alpha and MATLAB provide. I suspect either my arithmetic is incorrect or I've missed an important concept possibly to do with complex roots?

My workings so far are: $$ \int_{-1}^1 x^{1/3}\cdot f_X(x)\,dx $$ 
$$\int_{-1}^1 x^{1/3}\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)dx$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1 x^{4/3}+x^{1/3} dx $$
$$\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{3x^{7/3}}{7}+\frac{3x^{4/3}}{4} \right]^{x=1}_{x=-1}$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{12x^{7/3}}{28}+\frac{21x^{4/3}}{28} \right]^{x=1}_{x=-1}$$
$$\frac{1}{56}\left[12x^{7/3}+21x^{4/3}\right]^{x=1}_{x=-1}$$
$$\frac{1}{56}\left[3x^{4/3}(4x+7)\right]^{x=1}_{x=-1}$$

Now this is the solution to the indefinite integral (confirmed using MATLAB) but if I proceed to substitute the bounds I worked out:

$$\frac{1}{56}\left[\left(3(1)^{4/3}(4(1)+7)\right)-\left(3(-1)^{4/3}(4(-1)+7)\right)\right]$$
$$\frac{1}{56}\left[\left(3(1)(4+7)\right)-\left(3(-1)(-4+7)\right)\right]$$
$$\frac{1}{56}\left[\left(3(11)\right)-\left(-3(3)\right)\right]$$
$$\frac{1}{56}\left[33-(-9)\right]=\frac{1}{56}(42)=\frac{6}{8}$$

However the answer should be $\frac{3}{7}$, and can be confirmed directly using $E[Z]=\int_{-1}^1z\cdot f_Z(z)\,dz$

Entering the integral into MATLAB or Wolfram Alpha provides a complex solution which makes me more confused as to whether it is my arithmetic or something else that's affecting my result.

Finally, I did observe that in order to obtain the result $\frac{3}{7}$, the final line in my workings out should be: $$\frac{1}{56}\left[33-9\right]=\frac{1}{56}(24)=\frac{3}{7}$$ But don't know how to obtain that result?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Correction: $f_{X}(x) = \frac{x+1}{2}$ not $\frac{x-1}{2}$. You did this mistake in the first step of computing expectation.

Comment: $(-1)^{4/3} = 1 \neq -1$

Comment: $((-1)^4)^{1/3} = 1^{1/3} = 1$ or $((-1)^{1/3})^4 = (-1)^4 = 1$

Comment: @expiTTp1z0 I was just thinking that as you were writing that down. Is there a reason why MATLAB, Wolfram Alpha and a scientific calculator doesn't recognise this? Cheers for all your help!

Comment: I think they interpret as follows: $(-1)^{4/3} = (e^{i\pi})^{4/3} = e^{i4\pi/3}$

Comment: @expiTTp1z0 ah thank you for that clarification. Cheers once again!

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left[X^{1/3}\right] 
&= \int_{-1}^1 x^{1/3}\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \int_{-1}^1 x^{4/3} + x^{1/3} dx\\[1mm]
&= \frac{1}{2} \left[ \frac{3}{7}x^{7/3} + \frac{3}{4}x^{4/3} \right]_{-1}^1\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left[ 
       \left(\frac{3}{7} + \frac{3}{4}\right) - 
       \left(\frac{3}{7}(-1)^{7/3} + \frac{3}{4}\sqrt[3]{(-1)^{4}}\right)   
 \right]_{-1}^1\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left[ 
       \left(\frac{3}{7} + \frac{3}{4}\right) - 
       \left(\frac{-3}{7} + \frac{3}{4} \right)   
 \right] \\ &= \frac{1}{2}\left[ \frac{6}{7} \right] = \frac{3}{7}
\end{align}